# HP 14" latptop a good choice for elementary OS - Model 14-cf1015cl

Tags: hardware, laptop, hp

I would like to get a smallish laptop for home computing and web app dev. I am new to elementary OS but would like to use linux. Will I be able to get elementary OS running on this machine?

SPECS:

Processor & Memory:

```
Intel® Core™ i5-8265U Processor at 1.6GHz
8GB DDR4 2400MHz RAM (1-DIMM)
```

Drives:

```
256GB PCIe NVMe M.2 Solid State Drive
No Optical Drive
```

Operating System:

```
Microsoft® Windows 10 Home (64 bit)
```

Communications:

```
Realtek Wireless-AC WLAN + Bluetooth® 4.2
HP TrueVision HD Webcam + Integrated Digital Microphones
```

Graphics & Video:

```
14" SVA BrightView WLED-backlit HD (1366 x 768) Display
Intel UHD 620 Graphics
```

Audio:

```
HD Audio with Stereo Speakers
```

Keyboard:

```
Full-size island-style Backlit Keyboard
```

Ports:

```
1x USB 3.1 Type-C
2x USB 3.1
1x HDMI 1.4b
1x Multi-Format Digital Media Card Reader
1x Combination Headphone-Out/Microphone-In Jack
```

Power Supply:

```
3-Cell 41WHr Lithium-Ion Battery
```

Answer (score 2):

It will work however you'll probably need to update the kernel and some packages since that cpu model is pretty new.

If you want to be completely sure that it works, look for a laptop that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 or lower preinstalled. Those will surely work with elementary. There are companies like System76, Purism or Dell that offer that kind of laptops.

Comment: And also test the OS live

Comment: Thanks, I was mostly worried about the PCIe NVMe M.2 Solid State Drive. I've seen those machines you mention but there is nothing in this price class

Comment: Yeah it will work fine

Answer (score -1):

you can basically install Linux on any laptop, but be advised you need to work around the uefi secure bios.